# How can I find what the unexpected character is?

Tags: angular, identityserver3

I have set up an identity server 3 server and have followed a course on pluralsight to set it up.  It seems to be working but when I send a request for a token to the server, I get an error: [image]

It says invalid char and I'm having a devil of a time trying to see what is being returned form the server.  This is the request from Angular 2:

```html
@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
  callbackUrl = encodeURI(window.location.protocol + '/' + '/' + window.location.host + '/tokenCallback.html');
  private _url = 'https://localhost:44328/identity/connect/authorize?' +
            'client_id=ketogeniqapiclientimplicit&' +
            'response_type=token&' + 'scope=ketogeniqapi&' +
            'redirect_uri=' + this.callbackUrl ; 
            

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  console.log('in token service')
  }

  getToken() {
    console.log('token service: get token')
    console.log('url = ' + this._url);
    return this.http.get(this._url)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error); 
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
  }
}
```

If I run the link in the image above from a browser, I get a message from Identity server: "The client application is not known or is not authorized."

This is the client definition:

```html
 public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
        {
            return new List<Client>() {
                new Client
                {
                        ClientName = "ketogeniqapiclient",
                        ClientId = "Ketogeniq (Client Credentials)",
                        Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,
                        ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                            {
                                new Secret(KetogeniqApiConstants.KetogeniqApiClientSecret.Sha256())
                            },
                        AllowAccessToAllScopes = true
                },
            new Client
                {
                    ClientName = "ketogeniqapiclientimplicit",
                    ClientId = "Ketogeniq (Implicit)",
                    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessToAllScopes = true,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        XamlwareStsConstants.XamlwareStsAngular + "tokentCallback.html"
                    }
                }
            };

        }
```

Here's the stack trace.  I found a line that said the unexpected char was '<', but that isn't in anything except the callback html and that never get's called.
[image]

Here's the response:
[image]
I'm at a complete loss on what to do next.  Anyone see any glaring error?

Comment: The error doesn't give you any extra information as to what the invalid character is or where to search? It would seem that the error is just an object that you can expand.

Comment: The error seems to provide more details but it is cut off. What does it show if you expand the node?

Comment: Looks like you're not URL encoding the params.

Comment: Added more on the error object.

Comment: The error message is quite weird. I would investigate what `response` in `response => response.json()` actually looks like. I guess the response is not JSON at all.

Comment: Brock, I have other http calls that work and I haven't had to encode any of them yet.  I'm assuming that the http provider takes care of that...

Comment: Gunter, For me that's the problem.  I open up response, and can't find anything that shows what the return is.  Any hints?

Comment: I know it's not too easy but AFAIR there is a way to see the `body` or similar that shows the response value. Can you post a screenshot of the output of `console.log(reponse)`?

Comment: I just updated the post with the response object.